# Aside from 'disappointment' is there a term for that negative emotion when the future you're dreaming didn't turn out well?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> People before the two world wars hold an optimistic attitude towards
> the future as evident in their films and literature—then a major war
> broke out in 1914, and another in 1939.

I want to know, if there's a word (aside from 'disappointment') for that kind of sad feeling when the future you're dreaming didn't turn out well as expected.

Comment: How about _disillusionment_?

Comment: Have you checked a thesaurus for synonyms of “disappointment”?

Comment: Please do check a dictionary. That'll be faster than waiting on us.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives to "disappointed could include:

- disillusioned
- let-down
- deflated
- bereft

If you make it clear *why* a person feels a certain way, that really opens up the possibilities for word choice, because the word doesn't have to be exactly synonymous with disappointment. For example, if you said "the failure to realise my hopes and dreams left me feeling empty", it would be clear to the reader that the source of your feeling of 'emptiness' was disappointment.

Comment: 'Regret' might be the best one.

Comment: @fred2 "Regret" is sometimes linked to disappointment but it is mainly used when there is an identifiable cause of the failure to realise something. For example, if you failed to act then you might regret your lack of action. I wouldn't use it if the hopes were expected to self-realise.